# Firebase onMessageReceived() not called in some devices with data payload when app is killed

Tags: android, firebase, android-service, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I know when app is killed then we need to send `data` payload in order to send push notification and `onMessageReceived()` method will invoke.

But after reading more than 100 SO answers and articles I concluded that on many devices `onMessageReceived()` does not invoke once they killed even with data payload.

Still is there any way that I can show notification in those devices.

Comment: Do you still send `notification` payload aswell or only `data`?

Comment: Only data payload

Comment: Are you also setting `content_available` key as `true`?

Comment: you  can create a service can be run in background and from system boot in case that your app killed

Comment: Did you check the play services and OS versions in those devices?

Comment: @Mohammed any example which you can give for reference.

Comment: @HarikumarAlangode it's OnePlus 5 and MI4

Comment: it does not work in all devices, sometimes if a device has the app killed he wont recieve the notification

Comment: Right Peter. But still is there any way?

Comment: @FaisalShaikh Check if the play services version in those devices is greater than 11.8.0

Comment: @HarikumarAlangode and if greater than 11.8.0 than? What is the soultion?

Comment: @FaisalShaikh No. What I mean is that make sure that the play services' version in all those devices are above 11.8.0. Firebase does not work below those versions.

Comment: @HarikumarAlangode the versions are fine and firebase is working. My issue is, `onMessageReceived()` not called in some devices when app is killed.

Comment: @FaisalShaikh Are you using latest version of firebase cloud messaging dependency? Lower versions had some bugs

Comment: Yes, I am using the latest version.

Answer (score -3):

Use this method id FirebaseMessaging class

```
@Override
    public boolean zzE(Intent intent) {
        Log.e(TAG, "zzE");
        Set<String> keys = intent.getExtras().keySet();
        Log.e(TAG, "" + keys);
        Iterator<String> it = keys.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "zzE " + it.next());
        }
        for (String key : keys) {
            try {
                Log.e("uniq", " " + key + " " + intent.getExtras().get(key));
                if (key.equals("data")) {
                    String cnt = intent.getExtras().get(key).toString();
                    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
                    NotificationModel model = gson.fromJson(cnt, NotificationModel.class);
                    int badgeCount = model.getCount();

                    Log.e("uniq", " badge count " + badgeCount);
                    ShortcutBadger.applyCount(this, badgeCount);
                    Log.e("uniq", " " + "end");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("uniqbadge", "zzm Custom_FirebaseMessagingService" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        return super.zzE(intent);
    }
```

Use this method, I m showing bagde to my app icon through this method from firebase when app is in killed state. You can send your data through intent and open your desired activity.